# How to obtain the synced twitter raw contact through the contacts api?

Tags: android, contactscontract

I have a user id from a synced contact, I now try to retrieve the raw twitter accounts that the sync adapter from the official twitter client creates. 
How would I specify the MIME Type for needed to filter for the Twitter Account?

The content of the MIME Type Column is:

> Column Name is: mimetype Content is:
>   vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.twitter.profile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad. Another Error made the result I wanted to get invisible to me.

The following code gives you the synced twitter contact:

```
Cursor rawTwitterContact = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, null, Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.twitter.profile'", new String[] { String.valueOf(userId) }, null);
```

Comment: Hi Janusz, does getting this give you Twitter information then?

Comment: probably it gives you some kind of user id, which you can further use with the twitter api